# Given two functions, find the volume of the solid of revolution when the region bounded by the functions is rotated about the line y=-2.

Tags: calculus, volume, mathematica

I am expected to use Mathematica to complete this task.

Given the functions $f(x)=\arctan x$ and $g(x)=2\cos x$, find the volume of the solid of revolution when the region bounded by $f$ and $g$, within the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$, is rotated about the line $y=-2$.

On paper, I sketched the solid, and found it to be a donut with a widened hole at one side.

The inner radius of the donut, then, was $IR=-2-\arctan(x)$, because that is the function on the inside of the donut. The outer radius was $OR=-2-2\cos(x)$, because that is the function on the outside of the donut.

Using Mathematica, I found the intersection points within the required interval to be $1.1331$ and $-2.17747$.

According to the formula for solid volume, I should integrate as follows:

$$V=\int \pi(OR^2−IR^2)dx,$$ which translates to:

$$V=\pi \int ((-2-2\cos x)^2−(-2-\arctan x)^2)dx,$$ using a definite integral from the intersection point $1.1331$ to $-2.17747$.

Mathematica evaluates this integral and provides the answer $94.5322 - 1.11022*10^{-16}i$.

It has been a while since I've used calculus; what am I misunderstanding or doing incorrectly? Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: It appears that Mathematica is assuming a complex domain. The complex part is essentially $0$ given sixteen decimal precision.

Comment: I did this volume by two different methods, (1) an integral similar to yours and (2) by Pappus's theorem. In both cases I get the volume to be $V\approx71.5079$.

Comment: Is my integral set up appropriately? If so, perhaps I need to work on my formatting/syntax within the program. If not, what have I done wrong?

Comment: The integral set up is correct but only for the donut in the middle of the range.  You have to set up the one at the left of the donut from $-\pi$ to 2.17747.  Aldo for the right side of the donut from 1.1331 to $\pi$.